# Can google cloud storage be mapped to gmail accounts?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am building an iOS app, which uses firebase for gmail authentication. Some user data is stored in firebase. The app will need to store lots of media files from user. I could store these media on firebase storage, however I cannot calculate per user storage capacity with firebase and thereby bill the user accordingly. I do understand that firebase storage is on Google cloud.

I am a new bio to Google cloud and firebase. I would like to know if Google Cloud platform is per user, or is it a platform for the entire app, to store the app's content. Is there any way Google Cloud platform links to google user's own storage capacity?

As the user authenticates with gmail account, I would want the app to link to the user's own google storage capacity and store the media files in user's own google storage. Is this possible with google cloud storage?

Answer (score 0):

If you ask the user for permission and you get it, then you can store files in their Google Drive. See here for documentation:

https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart

The Drive API is separate from the Google Cloud Storage API. Cloud Storage is used as a storage for your project. For your scenario you could still use Cloud Storage, but then you'd have to keep track of which user owns which file yourself if you want to bill them accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking along the same lines and was also taking a look at the Drive API documentation. I wanted to be doubly sure if I was doing the right thing. Will give it a go.